# Unable to push project into GitHub from vscode integration?

Tags: git

> git remote add https-//github.com/sathishbossn/Test_project07.git https://github.com/sathishbossn/Test_project07.git
> fatal: 'https-//github.com/sathishbossn/Test_project07.git' is not a valid remote name

Comment: Use a simpler name, like "me" instead of "https-//github.com/sathishbossn/Test_project07.git".

Comment: me?  can u explain?

Comment: Branch names are intended to be simple words that you could tell another person or use as a filename. Long names with metacharactes cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Git branch names are not allowed to have multiple consecutive slashes like `//`.

You can see all rules regarding branch naming on the git man page: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format

As the other comments already suggest you might want to consider a simpler branch name, for example your username `sathishbossn`.